# Random forest classification: if the response variable is constructed based on the explanatory variables does it make sense to do the model?

Tags: random-forest

I learned that Random Forest classification is particularly useful for identifying the importance of explanatory variables within a classification dictated by the categories of a response variable. However, if said response variable was constructed based on the explanatory variables, does it still make sense to run the model? Let me explain: I have 16 categorical explanatory variables (scores between 0 and 3) and a response variable with two categories (high and low condition) and I want to know which of the 16 explanatory variables best discriminates the two categories of the response. The point is that the latter is derived from the sum of the scores of the 16 explanatory variables. Is it ridiculous to do the Random Forest?
Thank you!

Comment: If you know at the start that the response variable is derived from some sum of the scores of the explanatory variables, then there may be better models than Random Forest.  But usually you do not start by knowing the relationship.

Comment: You know the exact relationship between the $16$ explanatory variables and the high/low outcome, $y = v_1 + v_2 + \dots + v_{15} + v_{16}$. There is no relationship to investigate.